The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server in laravel
When I create access_token and refresh_token using Laravel 11 passport then the following error occurs:

unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorizatio (truncated...)

Please help regarding this error:
$response = $http->post($uri, 
   ['form_params' => 
     [
       'grant_type' => 'password',
       'client_id' => '2',
       'client_secret' => 'vvHpMS4z4VmTKbPPa4zZZh1a64IWw9SR7RDoCNUu',
       'username' => 'admin@gamil.com',
       'password' => 'admin','scope' => '*',
     ],
]);`

All the steps have been followed but still the error occurs. This works in my old project but not in the new project.

Does this answer your question? Laravel Passport - Grant Type Not Supported

It's not recommended to use password grant tokens!

To enable the password grant, call the enablePasswordGrant method in the boot method of your application's App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider class.
public function boot(): void
{
    Passport::enablePasswordGrant();
}

